# Safe method to temporarily load second jquery library to wordpress

Tags: jquery

For testing (and completely temporary purposes) I want to load a jquery cdn into my wordpress header.php file. I can't determine if this is possible, and assume I'd need to setup for noconflict, etc. I've found documentation on it for the functions.php method, however the work for that would defeat the purpose of testing in header.php. Has anyone done this before?

Comment: It s not very clear what you want to do, and what is actually the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of rolling-your-own, just use a plugin designed specifically for that purpose for the CDN in question:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/use-google-libraries/